# 12-325v DC/DC Converter

Tags: dc-dc-converter, inverter

I'm toying with the idea of trying to build an inverter:  12v DC - 240v AC.

I'm thinking that I could use a buck-boost converter to convert 12v DC - 325v DC, then use an H-Bridge to chop the 325v DC up to an AC waveform.  I like the idea of doing it this way a little more than chopping up 12v DC - AC, and then using a transformer.

I'd like to supply around 2amps.

My question is simply whether this is within the realms of possibility?  Could this circuit feasibly work or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Edit:
I should clarify that I am unsure whether I'd be able to deliver the required current at these voltage levels with a buck-boost?

Comment: Boost only required as 300VDC >>> 12VDC. A sine wave output can be easily enough produced using mark space modulated PWM. Very standard. Very doable, but as noted , cost liable to B far more than off the shelf converters. As a learning exercise tha's fine.

Comment: 240vAC * 1.414 = 339.36v peak-peak. 240vAC * 2A = 480W. ~500W on the 12V side requires 500w = 12v * I --> I = 500/12 = ~42A (minimum.) With losses, expect 50A or more. I'd consider a [switching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switched-mode_power_supply) topology. There are many calculators out there such as [PowerEsim](http://www.poweresim.com/) but this is a long, long journey for a very specialized switcher.

Answer (score 3):

Variable frequency drives use your H-bridge chopping idea to control motor speed but these don't give good sinusoidal waveforms. Uninterruptible power supplies (UPS) do a better job.

You may be forgetting that in some ways your boost converter is doing the same job as the transformer based inverter but will be more complex.

Start pricing out your basic design and throw in a bit for whatever your time is worth. Then compare that we the cost of a 500 VA UPS. ;^)

Comment: This is a project to practise what I've been learning in University, so a level of complexity is desired :)  Converting the inverter design to variable frequency design would be a future project.

I should clarify that I am unsure whether I'd be able to deliver the required current at these voltage levels with a buck-boost?

Comment: @wevcore transistor is right. In one case you chop 325V at 2A, in the other, 12V at 50A, which is similarily difficult. However, in the first case, you also need a boost that is difficult to design, whereas in the second case, you need just an additional transformer. Moreover, the transformer can act as the inductor after the chopper whereas in the first case, you need two big inductors (cost). And with the transformer, you get galvanic isolation for free.

Answer (score 0):

I have very little real experience in this topic, but I have the idea that you should first double the voltage a couple of times with a fixed control signal to get at an intermediate voltage. From this stage you could do isolation (isolation is required if for example someone might attach solar panels to the battery while your inverter is running) and boost to the 400 volts DC. Then from the high voltage, drive the output chasing a sinusoid at a desired level. Anyone agree?